# Kotlin Flow, make flow conditional - only make call if true

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

Just starting to work with Kotlin flows.
I basically only want to insert an item into a room database if the record is unique.
I thought I could probably do this with `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` but `imageUrl` will always be unique. I always need to check against plateText.

So far I've got this and I was looking for ways that I could optimize it.

```
override fun flowSaveSomeStuff(plateText: String, imageUrl: String): Flow<Boolean> {
    return db.infoDao().getItems().map { list ->
        list.none { it.plate == plateText }
    }.filter { it }.map {
        db.infoDao().insertItems(
            plateInfo(
                plateText,
                imageUrl
            )
        )
        true
    }
}
```

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: You should add a unique constraint to your plateText and add OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE to not insert if the plateText already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use
`if exists select 1 from (table name) where (id or imageUrl) = :(your parameter i.e imageUrl)`
Query it in function and return Boolean
If it exists it will return true else false